# VLOOKUP with each 2 comparison arguments in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In Excel this is possible but in Google Spreadsheets somehow not.
what else can you do?

Comparison arguments:

- **comparison1:** A1=1 and B1=1,

Must be the same as

- **comparison2:** C1=1 and D1=1,

And as a result, a different column

- **different column result:** E1=OK

In excel this code works for it:

```css
EXCEL:
                 cells=   1 & 1 ;              ;  1 & 1 ;OK ;
= ARRAYFORMULA (VLOOKUP (A1 & B1; CHOOSE ({1,2}; C1 & D1; E1); 2, 0))
    
            evaluation= (   11  ;(index={11,YES};  11  ;OK); result 2=OK, 0=exact match
```

how do I get that in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets is more transparent than Excel when it comes to combining different columns into an array. You can use {..}

```
=vlookup(A1&B1,{C1&D1,E1},2,false)
```

It's unusual to do a vlookup just on one row though - you can do it in an array the same way

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(A1&B1,{C1:C2&D1:D2,E1:E2},2,false))
```

Comment: I compare street with city and need everything on the street is argument 3.
Streets can be double therefore the second search argument.
In ARRAY_CONSTRAIN you take the "\" in the EU instead of "," to put arrays next to each other.
but your answer is absolutely correct thanks.

**=VLOOKUP(A1&B1;{C1&D1\E1};2;0)**